# Update telephone number format to include country identifier

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

Being a beginner in SQL, I am trying to do the telephone fields to be noted in the format: '"+" + country identifier + telephone number'.

```
UPDATE public.contact 
   SET phone_number = CASE WHEN (country_code ='FR') 
                                AND phone_number NOT LIKE '+33%' 
                                AND phone_number <> NULL 
                                THEN CONCAT('+33', phone_number)
                           WHEN (country_code ='GB')and phone_number NOT LIKE '+44%' 
                                AND phone_number <> NULL 
                                THEN CONCAT('+44', phone_number)
```

I want to update telephone number format to include country identifier like : 0606080905-> +33606080905 if country_code='FR' . I am looking for a faster and less complex way than what I did.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You did not really add a question to your post. Where are you having problems? It could be helpful if you included sample data, the outcome you expect from your statement and where your current effort fails to get you the result you want.

Comment: i want to update telephone number format to include country identifier like : 0606080905-> +33606080905    if  country_code='FR' ...

Comment: Two mistakes: 1) `<> NULL` won't do what you want, use `IS NOT NULL` 2) the `CASE` must have a closing `END`.

Comment: thank you for the correction @LaurenzAlbe but I am looking for a faster and less complex way than what I did

Comment: Aside from the errors pointed out in other comments, your statement does not really do what you want, since it does not remove the leading zero when concatenating the country code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a regular expression using `regexp_replace`.

Imagine your data being:

```
                  +----------+--------------+
Table 'numbers':  | country  |    phone     |
                  +----------+--------------+
                  | FR       | 0606080905   |
                  | FR       | +33606080906 |
                  | GB       | 0123456789   |
                  | GB       | +44987654321 |
                  | GB       | NULL         |
                  +----------+--------------+
```

Then the following update would replace the leading `0` with the country code `+33` for all numbers that do not start with a `+xx` and have `FR` as country.

```
UPDATE numbers
   SET phone = REGEXP_REPLACE(trim(phone), '^(0)', '+33')
 WHERE country = 'FR'
```

Explained:

- the `^` means start of the string
- the `(0)` is the match that gets replaced (leading zero)
- the `+33` is the string that is used to replace it
- the `trim()` is just added for safety, in case there are leading spaces
- `NULL` phone numbers won't be affected, as they do not match

You could do this now as you did before with a `CASE WHEN` or something similar for each of the different possibilities. But since the expression always is the same, an easier way would be to have your country codes and their numerical mapping in a separate table:

```
                 +----------+--------+
Table 'mapping': | country  | prefix |
                 +----------+--------+
                 | FR       | +33    |
                 | GB       | +44    |
                 +----------+--------+
```

You could then do

```
UPDATE numbers n
   SET phone = REGEXP_REPLACE(trim(phone), '^(0)', prefix)
  FROM mapping m 
 WHERE m.country = n.country
```

and update all your numbers in one go:

```
+----------+--------------+
| country  |    phone     |
+----------+--------------+
| FR       | +33606080905 |
| FR       | +33606080906 |
| GB       | +44123456789 |
| GB       | +44987654321 |
| GB       | NULL         |
+----------+--------------+
```

---

---

EDIT: Previously, I had this needlessly complicated answer. You may need something like this if your phone number patterns are more diverse...

The following update would replace the leading `0` with the country code `+33` for all numbers that do not start with a `+xx` and have `FR` as country.

```
UPDATE numbers
   SET phone = REGEXP_REPLACE(trim(phone), '^(?<![+\d{2}])(0)', '+33')
 WHERE country = 'FR'
```

Explained:

- the `(?<![+])` is a *negative lookbehind assertion* that makes sure the regex only matches if there is no `+` followed by two digits before
- the `(0)` is the match that gets replaced
- the `+33` is the string that is used to replace it
- the `trim()` is just added for safety, in case there are leading spaces
- `NULL` phone numbers won't be affected, as they do not match

Comment: thank you very much @buddetmat it's very well to explain finaly it's work and it answers my question

Answer (score 0):

That's about as simple as it gets.

The only way I can imagine to speed up processing is to add a `WHERE` condition that avoids updating the rows that don't have to be modified.

You could also run several such statements in parallel, where each modifies a different part of the table.

As mentioned in the comment, `<> NULL` is **never** true.